# Multiple sources bound to same target dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to attach multiple (two-way) source bindings to a dependency property?  That is, so that if one source changes, the DP gets updated via one binding, and the change would then get propagated to the second source via the second binding.

In my scenario, the dependency property is in a user control, the first binding is to its internal view-model, and the second binding is for the view-model of the consumer of the user control.

---

Below is for illustration.  The consumer of the user control looks like this:

```
<MyControl SelectedValue="{Binding Selected,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Now "MyControl" has the "SelectedValue" defined as a dependency property.  The XAML for the control binds to its dependency property like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedValue,Mode=TwoWay,
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
          />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

"MyControl" has its internal data context set, in the control's constructor, to its own view model:

```
LayoutRoot.DataContext = new ViewModelForControl();
```

So far so good, but if I then attempt to add the second binding, that being the dependency property to a "SelectedInternal" property on the internal view-model --

```
SetBinding(SelectedValueProperty, new Binding("SelectedInternal") {
    Source = LayoutRoot.DataContext,
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
});
```

-- then the first binding is destroyed.  Is there a way to add this second binding while preserving the first?

Comment: If `SelectedInternal` is another dependency property, you could reverse the binding direction. Besides that, it isn't clear why you have that internal view model at all. UserControls usually shouldn't have an internal view model.

Comment: @Clemens I did consider just getting rid of the internal view model.  Is that how library controls are normally written, with no view model, instead code in the control's code-behind?  But what if I want to stick to an MVVM pattern?  Just not possible, maybe.

Comment: A pattern is of no use when it's only internal and hence private. You could as well add private properties to your control's code behind.

Comment: @Clemens I see what you mean about making the internal view model a dependency object and reversing the binding direction.  That's a good idea, too ...

Comment: @Clemens anyway if you want to post that as a quick answer I'll accept.

Comment: I agree with Clemens about custom controls do not need a viewmodel. Sure you can create one, but why, when everything is simply a private property on the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this being overthought?

Why not simply do the plumbing in the code behind of the custom control and forgo binding?

This can be done by

1. `SelectedValue` dependency property will utilize its changed handler and upon any change set `SelectedInternal` to the new value.
2. When `SelectedInternal` changes write to the property `SelectedValue`.

You create the VM on the control, so you have access to the VM and its property, which can provide the vectoring of the data for two way transfer.

---

At the end of the day binding is just getting a reference via reflection. In this case how one gets a reference is immaterial to simply writing back and forth between two properties.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you're right - probably a case of over-thinking / trying to follow an MVVM pattern where isn't not applicable.

Comment: @McGarnagle, I do understand and have been there myself where one is thinking about a specific route taking a *high* road so to speak, and not seeing the other road. :-)